# Is there a better way to access this dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I kinda new to python and have done programming, I know this is basic but my brain is melted right now.

I need to classify an id which represents a category , ex:
id: 12312 => Food
id: 123132 => Food

but I'm typing every `id` with the category in the dict, there's a better way of doing this :
like : `{[food:{12132,1444,54556,444},gas:{233,566,555}]}`
but then it needs to look by that value and provide the corresponding cat...

here's my code

```py
def clasificadorTipoGasto(id):
    dict = {
        131794442: "Gastos Menores", 101602465: "Supermercados",
        130403899: "Supermercados", 101793198: "Supermercados",
        101796822: "Supermercados", 101787589: "Supermercados",
        130246491: "Restaurantes", 124003091: "Restaurantes",
        101658347: "Restaurantes", 130123314: "Restaurantes",
        130751366: "Restaurantes", 101568224: "Restaurantes",
        130640726: "Restaurantes", 101808152: "Restaurantes",
        130389586: "Restaurantes", 101582936: "Air Fare",
        101068744: "Combustible", 101726997: "Combustible",
        130551618: "Combustible", 101033738: "Combustible",
        130274487: "Misc", 112107388: "Misc",
        130900663: "Misc", 101036354: "Misc"
    }

    if id in dict.keys():

        return dict[id]
    else:
        return "general"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.get` will try to return the value mapped to the given key, but return a default value if that lookup fails, rather than raise a `KeyError`:

```
def clasificadorTipGasto(id):
    d = {...}

    return d.get(id, "general")
```

If you are trying to *generate* that dict `d` from another dict that maps categories to distinct ids, then try

```
ids = {"food": {12132,1444,54556,444}, "gas": {233,566,555}}
d = {cat_id: category for category in ids for cat_id in ids[category]}
```

Comment: This should be stupid question but, now I need to make compare 01239129 numbers as Strings , I have tried encapsulating '20320' the numbers, now it throws everything As "General" , is not classifying.. @chepner

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return:

```
return d.get(id, "general")
```

The second arguement here is the default value which will be returned if key is not found